# How can I declare a counter inside of my recursive function? (Additive Persistence: Coderbyte)

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion

While working through some Coderbyte challenges, I was able to solve the following problem recursively, but was hoping to get some feedback on how I can improve it.

> Have the function AdditivePersistence(num) take the num parameter being passed which will always be a positive integer and return its additive persistence which is the number of times you must add the digits in num until you reach a single digit.
>
> For example: if num is 2718 then your program should return 2 because
>   2 + 7 + 1 + 8 = 18 and 1 + 8 = 9 and you stop at 9.

My submitted, working recursive solution is below. How can I place "count" into my function without letting it get "reset" every time I recurse?

```
var count = 0;
function AdditivePersistence(num) {
  count = 0;
  if (num < 10) {
    return count;
  }
  if (num > 10) {
    count++;
    AdditivePersistence('' + num.split("").reduce(function(a,b) {
      return parseInt(a) + parseInt(b)
    }));
  }
}
```

Here's my broken attempt at moving the counter within the function... would appreciate any pointers for my beginner-self. Beyond just fixing the code, I'd love it if there are other great methods for solving this puzzle!

```
function AdditivePersistence(num) {
  var count = 0;
  (function recurse(num) {
      if (num < 10) {
      return count;
      }
      if (num > 10) {
        count++;
        recurse('' + num.split("").reduce(function(a,b) {
        return parseInt(a) + parseInt(b);
        }));
      }
    })();
  return count;
}
```

***Edit: I just tried with a while loop below***

```
function AdditivePersistence(num) {
  var count = 0;
  while (num >= 10) {
    count++
    num = num.toString().split('').reduce(function(a,b) {
      return parseInt(a) + parseInt(b);
    })}
  return count;          
}
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Use tail-recursion (that is, pass the 'accumulator' variable as the last param of a recursive function).

Comment: In your first code block you are hiding the outer count variable by re-declaring it btw.

Comment: Your problem is the scope of `var count = 0;` which you somehow expect to be global.

Comment: Note that `num < 10` and `num > 10` doesn't cover all the possible values of `num`.

Comment: Hi all - sorry about that, my actual code didn't have a count declared within the function (of the first code block) - that was my mistake in transferring onto here, apologies.

Comment: @MattBurland ^ since he is returning in the first if he should omit the second if condition.

Comment: @MattBurland - good point, what would be another way to cover the values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to extend @georg's answer and provide a full implementation

```
var additivePersistance = (function () {
    function sumOfDigits (n) {
        var ret = 0;
        n.toString().split('').forEach(function (i) {
            ret += parseInt(i, 10);
        });
        return ret;
    }
    return function additivePersistance (n) {
        if (n < 10) {
            return 0;
        }
        return additivePersistance(sumOfDigits(n)) + 1;
    }
}());
```

This implementation hides the sumOfDigits as a helper method using a closure.

```
additivePersistance(2718); // 2
```

This closure idea can also serve to create a psudo static variable in the recursive function. Follow this form.

```
var func = (function () {
    var staticCounter = 0;
    return function func() {
        if (staticCounter++ > 20) {
            return 0;
        }
        return func() + 1;
    };
}());
```

Here the body of the inner func method is using the variable staticCounter accross all calls to the outter func.

Answer (score 5):

The idea is simple

```
AdditivePersistence(n):
   if n < 10
      return 0
   else
      return 1 + AdditivePersistence(sum-of-digits(n))
```

Strictly speaking, there's no need for the recursion here - that's essentially a normal `while` loop.

Comment: Strictly speaking, I don't think you ever *need* recursion. Anything with recursion should be rewritable as an iterative loop.

Comment: Thanks, I implemented a while loop and edited my original post. I guess I'm trying to understand how I can "protect" the counter in a recursive situation.

Answer (score 1):

```
var count = 0;

function AdditivePersistence(num)
{
    // make the number into a string so that each digit can be taken
    var num_string = num.toString();
    // this will hold each digit
    var numbers = [];
    // iterate through each digit as a character
    for(var i = 0; i < num_string.length; ++i)
    {
        // add the character converted to a number into the numbers array
        numbers.push(parseInt(num_string[i]));   
    }
    // this will hold the value of all the digits added together
    var total = 0;
    // iterate through the digits
    for(var i = 0; i < numbers.length; ++i)
    {
        // add each digit to the total
        total += numbers[i];
    }
    // if larger than the total
    if(total > 10)
    {
        // increase the count
        ++count;
        // redo it again
        AdditivePersistence(total);
    }
    else
    {
        // return the total amount of tries
        return (++count);
    }
}
```